# What message is sent when the mouse moves?

Tags: winapi, pywin32

I read that [`mouse_event()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) has a `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` message.

When I send a `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` message, the cursor moves.

Similarly, when I try to *drag and drop* by sending the `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN`, `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` and `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` messages to Paint, it works.

However, when I try to *drag and drop* something on another application, `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` work, and `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` moves the cursor, but the application doesn't seem to handle the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` message (the selected item doesn't move).

My question is: is there anything other than `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` that is sent when the (hardware) mouse is moved and that can be handled by the application? I've read that a [`DoDragDrop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-dodragdrop) function exists, could this be related?

EDIT: The application is developped using Unity, I read that there is [MouseMoveEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.MouseMoveEvent.html) but I guess that this event is related to the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` message. Also, there exists a [MouseDrag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventType.MouseDrag.html) event, maybe this is the event the application is handling. But how to simulate this event using **winapi**?

### Code

This is the code that works on Paint

```
def drag_and_drop(
        from_x: int,
        from_y: int,
        to_x: int,
        to_y: int
) -> None:
    to_x = round(to_x * 0xFFFF / (win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSCREEN) - 1))
    to_y = round(to_y * 0xFFFF / (win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSCREEN) - 1))
    win32api.SetCursorPos((from_x, from_y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, to_x, to_y)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
```

I also tried to add some delay between messages when sending to the application it does not work

```
def drag_and_drop(
        from_x: int,
        from_y: int,
        to_x: int,
        to_y: int
) -> None:
    to_x = round(to_x * 0xFFFF / (win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSCREEN) - 1))
    to_y = round(to_y * 0xFFFF / (win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSCREEN) - 1))
    win32api.SetCursorPos((from_x, from_y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.5)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, to_x, to_y)
    time.sleep(1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
```

And also tried using **PyAutoGUI**, it works on MacOS but not on Windows

```
def drag_and_drop(
    from_x: int,
    from_y: int,
    to_x: int,
    to_y: int
) -> None:
    pyautogui.moveTo((from_x, from_y))
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.dragTo((to_x, to_y), duration=2, button='left')
```

Comment: If you are trying to drag something outside of a window, its the window handler's responsibility to call `DoDragDrop()` in response to receiving `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` window messages, that is not something you can call on the window's behalf.  All you can do with `mouse_event()` (or `SendInput()`, which you should be using instead) is to inject mouse events into the hardware input queue, nothing more. The events get processed the exact same way as if they had come from the actual mouse hardware (assuming a mouse hook is not discarding them).

Comment: When I send `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN`, `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` and `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP`, I don't get the same behavior as doing a *drag and drop* with my mouse. So if the events are handled the same way, I'd have to send something else to replicate the same behavior. Is there another message that can be sent when moving the mouse and that I have to send?

Comment: There is no other event you can send. On the other hand, you didn't show any of your code, so nobody can tell you if you are even sending the events correctly to begin with. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Is there anything selected in your target app when you are sending those events? Look at this page, for example. You can drag the `Ask Question` button or the title with just the sequence mousedown-mousemove-mouseup, but to drag a word from text you have to double-click it first.

Comment: I also tried to send **MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN**, wait 2 sec to let me move the hardware mouse and send **MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP**, it works. The only thing is that the application seems to handle something else than **MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE**

Comment: `WM_MOUSEMOVE` belongs to a class of messages generated on demand rather than being explicitly posted into a message queue. They are colloquially referred to as *"low-priority messages"* and surface only during message retrieval from an otherwise empty message queue. My hypothesis is that the destination thread's message queue is non-empty (there's already the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message queued up), and the destination will see `WM_LBUTTONUP` before `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. You can verify this by adding an arbitrary delay after injecting the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` input event.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. Also I edited my post to add some informations.

Comment: My crystal ball says you’re doing this on a process that runs with UAC elevation.  No can do, shatter attack protection is solid.  Google “uac uiaccess” to learn more.

Comment: If so, how can `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` work?

Comment: If UAC were part of the issue, then no input would make it through, so that's not it. While you are seemingly trying to automate drag-and-drop operations, you should consider using UI Automation instead of fiddling with injected input (see [UI Automation Support for Drag-and-Drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/ui-automation-support-for-drag-and-drop)).